# Angular sending XHR when I need and HTTP request

Tags: angular, typescript, http, xmlhttprequest

I have a frontend in Angular and the backend is Java EE.  The issue I am running into is that the backend is expecting a standard Http request but Angular HttpClient sends XHR.  I get this error:
[image]

I think the two options I have are

1. somehow update the backend to allow CORS access-control-allow-origin which I would have to figure out how to do and assuming that I have the option to make changes to the backend
   ---OR---
2. change the front end to send an Http request and not XHR.

Since I am writing the frontend and can easily manipulate it, this is the option I am shooting for.

Below is the service for sending the Get request:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Survey } from './survey';
import { HttpErrorHandler, HandleError } from '../http-error-handler.services';

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SurveysDisplayService {

  surveysURL=environment.baseUrl+'api/surveys/';
  private handleError: HandleError;
  
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient, 
    httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandler) {
      this.handleError = httpErrorHandler.createHandleError('DisplayService');
     }

     //retrieve surveys from server
     getSurveys(): Observable<Survey[]>{
      return this.http.get<Survey[]>(this.surveysURL)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('getSurveys', []))
      );
     }

}
```

and here is the component.ts that uses the service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Survey } from './survey';
import { SurveysDisplayService } from './surveys-display.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-survey',
  templateUrl: './surveys-display.component.html',
  providers:[SurveysDisplayService],
  styleUrls: ['./surveys-display.component.css']
})
export class SurveysDisplayComponent implements OnInit {
  surveys:Survey[]=[];


  constructor(private surveysDisplayService:SurveysDisplayService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getSurveys();
  }

  getSurveys(): void {
    this.surveysDisplayService.getSurveys()
      .subscribe(surveys => (this.surveys=surveys));
  }

}
```

details for my Angular version
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is basically this: you need CORS headers from the server but you can not make it send them. To overcome this you might need a proxy that would do exactly that. I can suggest using HAProxy, here's a snipper from `this blog` that does what you need:

```
listen http-in
    mode http
    listen *:80

    # Add CORS headers when Origin header is present
    capture request header origin len 128
    http-response add-header Access-Control-Allow-Origin %[capture.req.hdr(0)] if { capture.req.hdr(0) -m found }
    rspadd Access-Control-Allow-Headers:\ Origin,\ X-Requested-With,\ Content-Type,\ Accept  if { capture.req.hdr(0) -m found }
```

Or you could use nginx (slightly more complicated to set up), you can find an example configuration [here](https://blogs.perficient.com/2021/02/10/nginx-proxy-for-cors/).

Answer (score 0):

> somehow update the backend to allow CORS access-control-allow-origin which I would have to figure out how to do and assuming that I have the option to make changes to the backend

You need to do that.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068) lists a couple of alternatives but if you don't have access to the backend then writing a new backend that acts as a proxy to the existing one is likely to be the only practical one.

---

> change the front end to send an Http request and not XHR.

XHR is an API used to make HTTP requests from JavaScript. It isn't a different kind of request.

If you want to switch to "not XHR" then you are looking at using a regular form submission or link which will *load a whole new page* and probably make using Angular pointless.

Doing that also requires that you change the backend, this time so it returns a new HTML document.